# Unity: GetPixels() always results in the colour black across whole image

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have an image (attached) which I'm using as a test. I'm trying to get and store all the colours of each pixel in an array.

I use the below code to do this;

```
    Texture2D tex = mapImage.mainTexture as Texture2D;

    int w = tex.width;
    int h = tex.height;
    Vector4[,] vals = new Vector4[w, h];

    Color[] cols = tex.GetPixels();
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            if(cols[y+x] != Color.black)
            {
                Debug.Break();
            }

            vals[x, y] = cols[(y + x)];
        }
    }
```

Where mapImage is a public Material variable which I drag in into the scene on the prefab. As you can see, I've added a debug test there to pause the editor if a non-black colour is reached. This NEVER gets hit ever.

Interestingly, I've got another script which runs and tells me the colour values (GetPixel()) at the click position using the same image. It works fine (different methods, but both ultimately use the same material)

I'm at a loss as to why GetPixels() is always coming out black?

I've also been considering just loading the image data into a byte array, then parsing the values into a Vector4, but hoping this will work eventually.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't indexing into the `Color` array properly. With the indices you are using, `y+x`, you keep checking the same values on the lowest rows of the texture, never getting past a certain point.

Instead, when calculating the index, you need to multiply the row that you are on by the row length and add that to the column you are on:

```
Texture2D tex = mapImage.mainTexture as Texture2D;

int w = tex.width;
int h = tex.height;
Vector4[,] vals = new Vector4[w, h];

Color[] cols = tex.GetPixels();
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        int index = y * w + x;
        vals[x, y] = cols[index];
    }
}
```

From the documentation on `GetPixels`:

> **The returned array is a flattened 2D array, where pixels are laid out left to right, bottom to top (i.e. row after row).** Array size is width by height of the mip level used. The default mip level is zero (the base texture) in which case the size is just the size of the texture. In general case, mip level size is `mipWidth=max(1,width>>miplevel)` and similarly for height.

Comment: @NeoKuro if this answered your question successfully please be sure to click the grey check mark next to this answer to mark it as the accepted answer. It will give me some points and help other people with similar questions find this answer!.

Comment: Thanks, looking at it its such a silly mistake...haven't been feeling well lately so thanks for the help ^.^

Comment: You know, you don't have to calculate that index at all. This answer nicely shows you how to get the index for any _specific_ pixel, but when you loop over _all_ of them, you can just initialise `int index` to 0 _outside_ the loops, and increment it with `index++` after getting the current pixel. That avoids doing a relatively heavy multiplication action on every single pixel in the image.